# Implement google login in existing mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-signin

I have a MVC project without Identity (custom authentication). But then I want to implement Google and Facebook authentication to it.

I created a project apart of this to see how microsoft does that in MVC Identity Authentication. I was able to implement part of it.  Right now I have button that invoke the google authentication page, when I select my email to login it has an error with - **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch** - but I force in URL to match with mine URL, which works.

Google is able to invoke my Action in Account Controller, however and looking to MVC base code that I copied, I'm not able to retrieve information about the user.

This is my method that returns null in loginInfo

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoginWithGoogle(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

THis is the AuthenticationManager

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```

How can I get information from google authentication? I'm able to do this by javascript but I would like how to do only with C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you google for this, there's a lot out there I'm pretty sure. I think even when you're in Visual Studio and creating a new project, you can tell it you want to use some kind of OAuth https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: Yes, but I didn't created a project with OAuth at start, and now I'm trying to implement Google Auth but I have that info empty

Answer (score 2):

I have recently created custom google login project. I am using Claims to store user detail but you can use your custom logic.

Please find it on GitHub. It is with detailed steps.

https://github.com/kishancool11/GoogleLoginMVC

You can use LoginWithGoogle in place of GoogleLoginCallback.

Comment: Why do this when MVC already implements Google login? The [link to the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) is in the comments. Enabling this requires only a few changes in the configuration code

Comment: Thanks. But what if somebody don't want to use all Identity classes and it's methods. Specially, with existing project where people are not using Identity. This guild line by Microsoft is based on Identity only. using Identity 1.0 or 2.0 is good practice but it is very complected to mange. We can use session/cookies/claims or anything we want in place of this default one, And most of people not understand what these pre-defined action are doing in AccountController. So,this POC is with only required things we need for google login in MVC.